# Python Packet Sniffer

Tags: python, pcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, winpcap

What Python module should I be using to sniff packets? I don't need anything too complex, I just need to get the data out of some packets being sent to my computer.  I am using Python 2.6 and Windows 7, and I have installed WinPcap 4.1.2.

So far I've seen people suggest pcapy and pypcap, but when I try to install those, they both fail and tell me I am missing msvcr71.dll even though it is on my computer. Also, the python-libpcap sourceforge page seems to be unavailable, so I can't try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you want to use a ready-made wrapper, but keep in mind that you can always use Ctypes to directly access the capture functions.

See:
http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/ctypes.html

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm reading through the page you linked to, but could you give me a bit more of a shove in the correct direction? I have never done anything with networking before and I also haven't used ctypes, so this is all new to me.

Comment: That would be a pretty low level way to access the pcap functionality.  Really for wrtting  python wrapper around the pcap software.  Just try to follow the tutorials at http://www.winpcap.org/.  They will assume C, but you are going to use python.  (w/ the ctypes translation layer.)

Answer (score 0):

py-pcap from dirtbags.net doesn't depend on a pcap lib so it might work for you. Though, I'm not sure how fast it is or if it works on windows.

http://dirtbags.net/py-pcap.html